# Dictionary multiple key for same value "and more"

Tags: swift, dictionary, key

Pretty basic but I'm hoping there is a shortcut that I'm not aware of:

I have a dictionary with 51 key/value pairs. First key is 0 then 1, etc all the way to 50.

I want my last key to be "50 or over" as they will all have the same value. Can you do something like 50... or something along those lines?

Comment: so are you trying to access your 51st key by any integer 50 and over so that `value[50...n]` -> `value[50]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by making a custom struct that wraps a dictionary.
This code isn't tested - and assume you want to store strings in the dictionary.  But that should be easy enough to modify.

(Updated for [Alexander's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander-reinstate-monica) comment)

```
struct CustomDictionary {
   let maxIndex: Int = 50
   var vals: [Int, String]
   subscript(index: Int) -> String {
       get {
            return vals[min(index, maxIndex)]  
       }
       set(newValue) {
            vals[min(index, maxIndex)] = newvalue 
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is just what I was going to suggest. But you can better express it as `return vals[min(index, maxIndex)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this rule for accessing a dictionary. You must use an exact key.

However, this is a pretty easy issue to handle. I suppose that your key will be a number, let's say 57 is an example that you would like to handle. You can do a simple rule by yourself:

```swift
    let number = 57
    let key = number > 50 ? "50+" : String(describing: number)

    dictionary[key] // => will return your number
```

Basically you will have to find out your key given you have the number. This code assumes that you will have to store the item for more than 50 at the key `"50+"`, but you can use anything you want instead of `"50+"`

On the other hand, if you used directly integers as keys for your dictionary, then you can store at the key `51` and the code above transforms into

```swift
    let number = 57
    let key = number > 50 ? 51 : number

    dictionary[key] // => will return your number
```

but in this case I suggest to use arrays, as a dictionary with integer keys which are also continuous (e.g. all the integers in the range 1-51) is the exact same thing as an array and in fact you can use the exact same idea as above.